# Topological properties of floating point number

Tags: general-topology

if i name $X_{e,m}$ the set of the signed floating point number with $e$ bit for exponent, and $m$ bit for mantissa is it possible, using general topology tools that for $(e,m) \rightarrow (\infty,\infty)$ then $X_{e,m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Apparently i haven't found anything in literature about topological structure of floating point set.

I was trying to build a topology over the set $Y = \bigcup_{e,m} X_{m,n}$, specifically the order topology but i can't find a linear order which make sense to use, build a topology using order criteria i think it's the best think to do...

My goal is to study which relationships there are between the real number set e floating point number set, which are a discretization of the real numbers.

Regards

Probably i've written very bad what i want to do... i will try to explain better basing on your feedback.

Comment: What do you mean by $X_{e,m}\to{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Basically that if you increase the digits number than the set tends to the real number.

Comment: Dear @Lukkio. I see that, although you have already asked 7 question in this site and received answers in 6 of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of possible floating-point numbers is finite and therefore consists only of isolated points. Thus the subset topology on $X_{e,m}\subset\mathbb R$ equals the *discrete topology*, which is not terribly interesting, topologically speaking.

Your $Y$ is the set of all [dyadic rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), that is, numbers of the form $a/2^b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. This is a countable set with a dense total order and no maximum or minimum, and is therefore homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ (but is not the same *set* as $\mathbb Q$).

(Or, if by "floating-point number" you mean something that includes representations of $\pm\infty$, and you identify the infinities in different $X_{e,m}$s, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$).

Comment: Ok, but i'm not interested to "set" $X_{e,m}$ but to a limit of a family of set $X_{e,m}$. I know about the continuity stuff, but for the moment i'm interested if it is possible to proove that using $(e,m) \rightarrow (\infty,\infty)$ than $X_{e,m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Lukkio: You would have to provide a concrete meaning for those "$\to$"s before you can start speaking about proof. Your $Y$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and therefore $\mathbb R$ is the topological completion of $Y$, but I'm not sure how one would shoehorn that fact into a technical meaning of $\to$ here.

Comment: Sorry... informally speaking it's a "limit", very very informally. But i don't think i can define "limit concept" without a topological structure, isn't? But my point are not floating point number but set of floating point number. I know it's a bit twisted, but i just want to look into this stuff a bit.

Comment: I just retrieved this question, i wonder if there's any serious study on the mathematical properties (topologically speaking) of the floating point number set. Is there something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If infinite precision floats (infinite sequences of digits, and an integer for the order of magnitude) are used, then the space is $\mathbb{N} \times 2^\omega$. Addition of floats would not be continuous for this topology.